# My boot menu is sluggish

Tags: boot, dual-boot, cinnamon

I use linux mint tifa cinnamon.
When I boot my laptop it welcomes me with, I think it's called grub menu?, black screen with white text prompt me to choose Linux mint or other 3 options.
That menu screen is very slow it takes around 1 second to recognize my input.
For example, I press arrow key down, it takes one second to go down.
Other than this my linux works just A-okay.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  Linux Mint is not Ubuntu, nor official flavor of Ubuntu, thus off-topic here.  SE's Unix & Linux is where you should ask (see on-topic link)

Comment: Questions about Linux Mint are on topic at https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is skip the GRUB boot screen that's asking you to choose an OS to boot into you can do this by editing the GRUB config file, in Ubuntu this is at:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Change the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` and `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to the following values:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Then run update GRUB from the config file:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then, reboot and you should skip the GRUB boot screen.

Comment: Thx so much i worked!